# No eclipse console output running JBOSS EAP6 on standalone mode

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I'm trying to start JBOSS EAP6 from inside eclipse on standalone mode and everything occurs correctly but the window console output from eclipse stays blank.

My settings are below

```
-mp "D:/portal/jboss-eap-6.1.0/modules" -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -b 0.0.0.0 --server-config=standalone-full-ha.xml 
-server -Xms1512m -Xmx1512m -XX:MaxPermSize=768m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true 
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true 
-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file="D:/portal/jboss-eap-6.1.0/standalone/log/boot.log" 
-Dlogging.configuration="file:/D:/portal/jboss-eap-6.1.0/standalone/configuration/logging.properties" 
-Djboss.home.dir="D:/portal/jboss-eap-6.1.0"
```

When I run from outside eclipse I can see the log normally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've discovered the problem. The original `standalone-full-ha.xml` of the jboss-eap-6.1 doesn't come with the console-handler by default as the others like domain.xml.

So once i've put this

```
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>

        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
```

everything worked correctly!

Comment: I had both 6.1 and 6.3 installed. 6.1 (and every other jboss instance I have ever downloaded had logging to console by default). I had to add these lines for 6.3 though. Thanks.